# What is the reason behind C# allowing the overloading of interface properties?

Tags: c#

It's highly likely this question will reveal a misunderstanding on my part of how to create good interfaces...

Assume I have a class **ItemClass** and it's implementing the **IItemInterface** interface, like so:

```
public class ItemClass : IItemInterface /* ..... */
```

I also have the following interface:

```
public interface ClassInterface
{
    List<IItemInterface> Items;
}
```

Now, lets say in a specific implementation of this interface, I want to my Items property to be a more specific than a simple list of **IItemInterface**. C# allows me to override the **ClassInterface** Items property and do this *(the code compiles/runs perfectly)*:

```
public class MyClass : ClassInterface
{
    public List<ItemClass> Items { get; set;  }

    IList<IItemInterface> MyInterface.Items
    {
        get { return this.Items; }
    }
}

// Method somewhere else
public void foo()
{
    MyClass bar = new MyClass();
    bar.Items = new List<ItemClass>();
    // etc....
}
```

My question is: why does C# allow me to do this? I know you are not allowed to overload properties, so why is an interface treated differently?

Comment: Is `MyInterface` supposed to be `ClassInterface`?

Comment: That's not overloading. You are implementing the interface explicitly.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I wondered why I wasn't able to find any resources for my question - turns out I was asking it wrong. Thank you!

Comment: you can also read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)